# Calc 2: find integral of a fraction with natural log e and square roots

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm not sure how to approach the following problem.

Evaluate the integral: $$\int \frac{24 e^{\sqrt{3x}}}{2 \sqrt x} dx$$

I assume I can do $24/2 = 12$ and take the factor of $12$ out of the integral.
But not sure what to do from here.  Do I let u equal something in the integral?  If so what?

Also is $\sqrt{3x}$ the same as $\sqrt 3
\cdot \sqrt x$?

A step through would be appreciated.

Comment: Let $u=\sqrt{3x}$.  What’s $du$?

Comment: $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$. Look at it as $(ab)^{1/2} = (a)^{1/2}(b)^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Put $y =\sqrt x$. The integral becomes $12\int e^{\sqrt 3 y} dy=24 \frac {e^{\sqrt 3 y} } {\sqrt 3}=24 \frac {e^{\sqrt 3 \sqrt x} } {\sqrt 3}$ plus a constant.